# Mean a grid to decrease resolution of a Netcdf

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a very large dataset ('Tree cover') at a very high resolution of about 250m (specifications below). I want to convert this dataset to 0.25-degree resolution in python.

```
####Specification of the dataset
<xarray.DataArray 'Percent_Tree_Cover' (lat: 43575, lon: 70875)>
[3088378125 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
    time     object 2001-03-06 00:00:00
  * lat      (lat) float64 -50.0 -50.0 -49.99 -49.99 ... 40.77 40.78 40.78 40.78
  * lon      (lon) float64 -88.45 -88.45 -88.45 -88.45 ... 59.19 59.2 59.2 59.2
Attributes:
    grid_mapping:  crs
    valid_min:     0
    valid_max:     100
    long_name:     Percent_Tree_Cover
```

What I want is to mean every `Treecover` pixel in that falls in a 0.25-degree grid (something like the figure below). I want to `mean` high-resolution layer in the respective grid of lower resolution pixel. For the figure below, one green pixel covers 9 white pixels, as I am assuming that the pixel's in both the layers have a non-decimal ratio or are perfectly aligned [The blue window on the high-resolution pixel defines the odd pair].

[image]

For this, I have come up with a code (mentioned below and works fine):

```
TC = xr.open_dataset('MOD44B.006_250m_aid0001.nc').Percent_Tree_Cover[0]
TC = TC.sel(lat = slice(50,-50))
TC = TC[::-1]
TC

## For 0.25 resolution
lon = np.arange(-179.875,180,0.25);
lat = np.arange(-89.875,90,0.25);

TC_nan = TC.where(TC != 200) #For removing 200 as NaN

TC_reshaped_nanmean = np.zeros((720,1440))

for y in tqdm(range(lat.shape[0]-1)):
    for x in range(lon.shape[0]-1):
        TC_reshaped_nanmean[y,x] = np.nanmean(TC_nan.sel(lat = slice(lat[y],lat[y+1]), lon = slice(lon[x],lon[x+1])).values)
        #print(lat[y],lat[y+1],lon[x],lon[x+1])

np.save('TC_nanmean_2001.npy', TC_reshaped_nanmean)
```

The above code takes about **1.5 hours to complete**.
Do provide your suggestions about the credibility and how to reduce the time of the code.

Comment: I have done spatial averaging using a module/subroutine written in `Fortran` and compiled it using `f2py` - simple subroutine `get_average(xin,yin,zin,xout,yout)`, where the `xin`,`yin` are the input coordinates and `zin` are the values. `xout` and `yout` specify the output grid (I am using regular, so it is easy to get the location in indices at output grid based on xin and yin value). If the number of points is very large, pure `Python` implementation is much slower... Perhaps there is some quick solution using `NumPy`, but so far, writing `Fortran` was quicker for me.

Comment: Perhaps this answer could serve as an example for your problem: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329945/should-resampling-downsampling-a-raster-using-rasterio-cause-the-coordinates-t
as the `rasterio` module has some method for downscaling.